# How to extract the value of xml node to a variable in powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am working to build a Power shell script that reads a XML file and extracts the values from the nodes to make further calculations. How could I extract the node values to variables?

I have written code using XMLDOC in PS to read the file and extract the values in Power shell. I am able to get the attribute value of a single node. I am not able to extract the node value which has attributes too and there are multiple occurrences of the node.

> Test.xml

```
<abc>
  <body>
    <Rows Count="02">
      <Row>
        <a ID="1">Name1</a>
        <a ID="2">Naresh</a>
        <a ID="3">Arvind</a>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <a ID="1">Name2</a>
        <a ID="2">Sathish</a>
        <a ID="3">Kannan</a>
      </Row>
    </Rows>
  </body>
  <abc>
```

> Code

```
   [xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content E:\Desktop\Test.xml 
   $nodes = $XmlDocument.SelectNodes('//Rows') 
   $A = $nodes.GetAttribute("count")  

   if ($A -eq '02')
    {
     $B = $XmlDocument.abc.Body.Rows.ROW.a | Where-Object {$_.ID -eq '2'}
    }
```

> Expected Result

Variable A should get "02"(only value) and "Naresh","Sathish" (only values) should be stored in 2 different variables

> Actual Result

Variable A gets "02" - it is working
both "Naresh" and "Sathish" are stored in Variable B but stored with the IDs and headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[xml] $str = @'
<abc>
  <body>
    <Rows Count="02">
      <Row>
        <a ID="1">Name1</a>
        <a ID="2">Naresh</a>
        <a ID="3">Arvind</a>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <a ID="1">Name2</a>
        <a ID="2">Sathish</a>
        <a ID="3">Kannan</a>
      </Row>
    </Rows>
  </body>
  </abc>
'@


$a = $str.abc.body.Rows.Row.a | Where-Object {$_.ID -eq '2'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty '#text'
```

Use the Select-Object property and you will be having only Naresh & Sathish in output.

[image]

Comment: Can we extract "Naresh" and "Sathish" in two different variables? 
$A = Naresh
$B = Sathish

Could we use where-object for the first fields?

Comment: I used an array to split the values to two variables